# url_to_postid method in walker_nav navigation menu causing exceptionally high TTFB

Tags: menus, navigation, performance, walker

I am using the walker class to create my custom mega menu, and using it to display post thumbnails at a menu depth of 2.

It seems using the url_to_postid method seems to be causing a high ttfb of >10s.
I initially thought it was an image size issue but even after compressing the images by 95% i seem to be getting the same ttfb.

When the offending code is removed ttfb drops dramatically to <1s, but the attachment images don't display.

Is there any other method I can use to get my thumbnails to display in the mega menu without such a massive drop in performance?

Walker.php code:

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){

//url_to_post id causing >10s ttfb
$postid = url_to_postid( $item->url );
$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postid);

   

if ( array_search( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes )&& $depth==0 ) {
    
    
    
 $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='topnavitem %s'><a href='%s' class=\"topnavtext\">%s</a> <span class='plus'><i class='fas fa-angle-down'></i></span>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) || array_search( 'current-page-parent', $item->classes ) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
} 

elseif ( array_search( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes )&& $depth==1 ) {
    $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='productsnav %s'><a href='%s' class=\"productsnavtext\">%s</a><span class ='sub-plus'><i class ='fas fa-angle-down'></i></span>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) || array_search( 'current-page-parent', $item->classes ) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
} 

 //$thumbnail using url_to_postid being called at a menu depth of 2 

elseif ($depth==2){
    $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='midnavitem %s'><div class='pictext'><img src='%s'/><a href='%s' class=\"midnavtext$postid\">%s</a></div>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? '' : '', $thumbnail,$item->url, $item->title );
}




else {
    $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='topnavitem %s'><a href='%s' class=\"topnavtext\">%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
}
 }

function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
$indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
if ($depth == 0) {
$output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-level-one\" role=\"submenu\">\n";
}


    if ($depth == 1) {
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-level-two\" role=\"subsubmenu\">\n";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain, but I'd wager that `url_to_postid()` is simply not a very fast function. You shouldn't need to use it though, since the original post ID is available from `$item`:

```
if ( 'post' === $item->object ) {
    $post_id   = $item->object_id;
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id );
}
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, I tried implementing the changes suggested. Unfortunately the <img src=> tag thats supposed to contain the url for the post thumb just states 'unknown' and no post thumbnails are displaying in the mega menu